# Fetching and comparing CFBundleVersion from plist

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, jailbreak

I'm trying to compare `CFBundleVersion` key of 2 Apps inside com.apple.mobile.installation.plist which include the info of every installed application on iPhone

```
NSString *appBundleID =@"net.someapp.app";
NSString *appBundleID2=@"net.someapp.app2";

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
         @"/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist"];
NSDictionary *User = [dict valueForKey:@"User"];

//get first app version
NSDictionary *bundleID = [User valueForKey:appBundleID];
NSString *appVersion = [bundleID valueForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

//get second app version
NSDictionary *bundleID2 = [User valueForKey:appBundleID2];
NSString *appVer2 = [bundleID2 valueForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

[dict release];
 
if ([appVersion isEqualToString:appVer2]) {
     NSString *str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Original Version: %@",appVersion];
     NSString *str2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2nd Version: %@",appVer2];
     NSString *msg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",str1,str2];
     UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
           initWithTitle:@"Same Versions!" message:msg delegate:nil
       cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show]; 
}
else {
     NSString *str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Original Version: %@",appVersion];
     NSString *str2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2nd Version: %@",appVer2];         
     NSString *msg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",str1,str2];
     UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
         initWithTitle:@"Different Versions!" message:msg delegate:nil
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show]; 
}
```

The version of both apps is currently set to 2.11.8

I am getting the following wrong result:
[image: Wrong Result]

If i set the NSString manually:

```
NSString *appVersion =@"2.11.8";
NSString *appVer2 =@"2.11.8";
```

i get the correct desired result:

[image: Correct Result]

I also tried other ways to compare the strings but the result was always the same, so i guess the problem is with fetching the values of the keys?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show the output of `NSLog(@">%@<", appVersion)` and `NSLog(@">%@<", appVer2)` ?

Comment: Hey there, okay so i added `NSLog(@"Same Versions!");` / `NSLog(@"Different Versions!");` `NSLog(@">%@<", appVersion); NSLog(@">%@<", appVer2);` and check this crazy output https://ghostbin.com/paste/gfwax the last number is showing some random things!!!

Comment: What happens if you release the dictionary _after_ comparing the strings and creating the alerts?

Comment: that's what happen! https://ghostbin.com/paste/2mwko works great! Thank you! i think this was also the cause of some crashes. Please write an answer so i can accept it :) Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so used to ARC that I am not 100% sure about the MRC rules anymore. But I assume
that you either have to `retain` the values `appVersion` and `appVer2` from the dictionary,
or alternatively, postpone the `[dict release]` until after the values are no longer needed.
Since you don't own the values fetched from the dictionary, they become invalid if the
dictionary is released.

(This would *not* be a problem if you compile with ARC!)

*Remark:* The designated method to get a value from a dictionary is `objectForKey:`.
`valueForKey:` works also in many cases, but can be different. It should only be used
for Key-Value Coding magic.